# How to fetch and pass variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know how to pass variables in Node.js

When I try to fetch and pass some variables to `ejs`,error something like below has occured.

```
    27|                 <div id="content">
 >> 29|                 <%=json%>
    30|                 </div>
json is not defined
```

My current work is like below. Are there any problem? If somone has opinion,please let me know.
Thanks

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
       console.log(json);    
       res.render("quiz.ejs", json);
    
      });
});

app.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log('server is running!');
});
```

```html
              <div id="content">
                  <%= json %>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is how you can do it

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
         console.log(json);
         res.render("quiz.ejs", {
            json: json
         });
      });
});
```

so, to print an object to the `template (ejs)` we first need to stringify it:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(json)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the rendering section of your code. Try sending second argument inside the curly braces as like

```
res.render('quiz.ejs', {json});
```